# next.js update page after form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props

I have a form component that resides in the sidpanel of my layout. When the form is submitted a few things can happen. If there is an error or validation issues then a message is logged. If there is no data returned from the API then a "no data available" message will appear. Instead of displaying these messages in the form component I would like to update the Index page with the message. I can't seem to figure out how to pass the form component data to the Index page.

Here is the form component:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import setHours from 'date-fns/setHours'
import setMinutes from 'date-fns/setMinutes'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import Canvas from 'components/canvas'
import styles from './form-controls.module.css'

export default function FormControls() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 17)
  )
  const [refreshRate, setRefreshRate] = useState()
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState()

  // const handleRegister = (data) => {
  //   alert(JSON.stringify(data))
  // }
  const RadioInput = ({ id, label, value, checked, setter }) => {
    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type='radio'
          checked={checked == value}
          onChange={() => setter(value)}
        />
        <span>{label}</span>
      </label>
    )
  }
  function epoch(date) {
    date = Date.parse(date)
    date = date / 1000
    return date
  }

  const [track, setTrack] = useState()

  const rightThisSecond = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const radioSelected = { refreshRate }
    console.log(radioSelected)
    const RefreshRateSelected = JSON.stringify(radioSelected, null, 4)
    // console.clear()
    // console.log(json)
    const beginDate = epoch(startDate)

    // ... submit to API or something
    const res = await fetch(
      `/api/tracks/timeseries/${beginDate}/${rightThisSecond}`
    )

    const datePicker = {
      startTime: beginDate,
      endTime: rightThisSecond,
    }

    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
    if (radioSelected.refreshRate === undefined) {
      console.log('select a radio')
      setCanvas(<h2>Make sure you select a refresh rate!</h2>)
    }
    if (data.error) {
      setCanvas(<h2>{data.error}</h2>)
    } else {
      data.unshift(JSON.parse(RefreshRateSelected))
      data.unshift(datePicker)
      setTrack(data)
      setCanvas(<Canvas data={track} />)
    }
    // return { props: { canvas } }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Hello</h3>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
          showTimeSelect
          dateFormat='MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa'
        />
        <div>
          <label>Refresh rate:</label>
          <RadioInput
            label='1000ms'
            value={1000}
            checked={refreshRate}
            setter={setRefreshRate}
          />
          <RadioInput
            label='500ms'
            value={500}
            checked={refreshRate}
            setter={setRefreshRate}
          />
          <RadioInput
            label='120ms'
            value={120}
            checked={refreshRate}
            setter={setRefreshRate}
          />
          <RadioInput
            label='60ms'
            value={60}
            checked={refreshRate}
            setter={setRefreshRate}
          />
        </div>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is the index page:

```js
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Controls from '../components/controls'
import Aside from '../components/aside'

export default function Index({ canvas }) {
  return <section>Hello: {canvas}</section>
}

Index.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      {page}
      <Controls />
      <Aside />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

As you can see I am trying to pass the `{canvas}` as a prop but since the page is loaded already I don't think I am handling this correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend looking into [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to pass data between components.